# Rsyslog rate-limiting ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, rsyslog

I'm testing rsyslog 8.16 on Ubuntu 16.04, and I have this message on my suyslog file

> rsyslogd[internal_messages]: 39340 messages lost due to rate-limiting

This is my configuration on /etc/resolv.conf

```
$ModLoad imuxsock
$ModLoad imklog
$ModLoad imjournal
$IMUXSockRateLimitInterval 0
$IMJournalRateLimitInterval 0

module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514")

module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="514")
```

Do you have  any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change anything in your **resolv.conf** file. By default, I think rsyslog can accept upto 20,000 messages in a 10 minute period. Open your **/etc/rsyslog.conf** file and look for the parameter:

```
$imjournalRatelimitBurst 20000
```

Here the rate limit is 20,000. You can change 20,000 to any value you like.

Comment: This cannot resolv the issue. This my rsyslog configuration

Comment: i have already tried this solution